# NSDateFormatter dateFromString issue in >4.0 SDK

Tags: cocoa, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am converting a string into a date object with this code.

```
    NSDateFormatter *formate = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [formate setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
 NSDate *date = [formate dateFromString:@"2010-11-17"];
```

But I am getting wrong date in the output. It gives me - '**2010-11-16 18:30:00 GMT**'.

I am getting right output in 3.0 SDK. Is this method changed in new SDK?

Thanks
Ankit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that the time zone iOS thinks you're in has changed, or that its definition changed, between iOS 3.x and 4.0? Or even that this changed in Mac OS X and you're running in the simulator? You definitely need to specify what time zone and calendar you're using in order to get repeatable results from date calculations.

I explicitly set a locale to use when trying to get dates from strings. If I control the string, I ensure it includes a timezone specification.